# play! + Tomcat : No suitable driver found sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, tomcat, playframework, playframework-1.x

I've got a play! (1.x) app that works fine if I user 'play run', either in dev/test/prod mode. But when I try to run it on a Tomcat server, I got this exception :

> 10-Feb-2014 12:32:48.196 SEVERE [http-apr-8080-exec-20]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception
>   sending context initialized event to listener instance of class
>   play.server.ServletWrapper  play.exceptions.DatabaseException: Cannot
>   connected to the database, No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1444;DatabaseName=Blabbla  at
>   play.db.DBPlugin.onApplicationStart(DBPlugin.java:161)    at
>   play.plugins.PluginCollection.onApplicationStart(PluginCollection.java:525)
>     at play.Play.start(Play.java:533)   at play.Play.init(Play.java:305)
>     at
>   play.server.ServletWrapper.contextInitialized(ServletWrapper.java:78)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4734)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)

I'm using play 1.2.7, Tomcat 8.0.1 (same problem with v7) and here is my config file :

> db.url=jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1444;DatabaseName=Blabbla
>   db.driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
>   jpa.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect

I already tried to put the driver into TOMCAT_DIR/lib but nothing changed

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a solution : use Microsoft driver for MsSQL instead of the JTDS one. JTDS works fine on standalone but not with Tomcat.

> db.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver